# When are the normal stress tensor components in a fluid equal?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, stress-strain, fluid-statics

When would $\sigma_{xx}=\sigma_{yy}=\sigma_{zz}=-p$, in an incompressible fluid?
While this is true for fluids at rest, under what kind of flows would it still
hold exactly? For example, I think it would hold in narrow-gap flows 
(lubrication approximation).

Comment: Only when at rest.

Comment: Thanks! I intended to ask if under some kind of flows, the relationship still holds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It no longer holds when the fluid is viscous, and is in motion.  Then, for an incompressible  Newtonian fluid
$$
\sigma_{ij} = -p\delta_{ij}+\mu (\partial_i v_j+ \partial_j v_i).
$$

Comment: Thanks! I intended to ask if under some kind of flows, the relationship still holds. Edited the question a little.

Comment: @nishaChandramoorthy Your question is answered above. If $\sigma_{xx}=\sigma_{yy}=\sigma_{zz}=-p$ then equation above implies that $\partial_xu=\partial_yv=\partial_zw=0$. This means that _locally_, in some reference frame, the fluid is at rest.